# Parallel execution of CREATE DATABASE statements result to an error but not on separate SQL Server instance

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using the latest version of Entity Framework on my application (but I don't think EF is the issue here, just stating what ORM we are using) and have this multi-tenant architecture. I was doing some stress tests, built in C#, wherein it creates X-number of tasks that runs in parallel to do some stuff. At some point at the beginning of the whole process, it will create a new database for each task (each tenant in this case) and then continues to process the bulk of the operation. But on some tasks, it throws 2 SQL Exceptions on that exact part of my code where it tries to create a new database.

Exception #1:

> Could not obtain exclusive lock on database 'model'. Retry the
>   operation later. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could
>   not be created. Check related errors.

Exception #2:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

It's either of those two and throws on the same line of my code (when EF creates the database). Apparently in SQL Server, when creating a database it does it one at a time and locks the 'model' database (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/poojakamath/2014/12/23/could-not-obtain-exclusive-lock-on-database-model-retry-the-operation-later-create-database-failed/)) thus some tasks that are waiting throws a timeout or that lock on 'model' error.

Those tests were done on our development **SQL Server 2014 instance (12.0.4213)** and if I execute, say, 100 parallel tasks there will bound to be an error thrown on some tasks or sometimes even nearly half the tasks I executed.

BUT here's the most disturbing part in all these, when testing it on my other **SQL server instance (12.0.2000)**, which I have installed locally on my PC, no such error throws and completely finishes all the tasks I executed (even 1000 tasks in parallel!).

Solutions I've tried so far but didn't work:

- Changed the timeout of the Object context in EF to infinite
- Tried adding a longer or infinite timeout on the connection string
- Tried adding a Retry strategy on EF and made it longer and run more often
- Currently, trying to install Virtual machine with a similar environment to our Dev server (uses Windows Server 2014 R2) and test on specific version of SQL Server to try to see if the versions have anything to do with it (yeah, I'm that desperate :))

Anyway, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B96F3LfFtwMERVJSOWJ1V1h5Z0E/view?usp=sharing) is a simple C# console application you can download and try to replicate the issue. This test app will execute N-number of tasks you input and simply creates a database and does cleanup right afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 observations:

1. Since the underlying issue has something to do with concurrency, and access to a "resource" which at a key point only allows a single, but not a concurrent, accessor, it's unsurprising that you might be getting differing results on two different machines when executing highly concurrent scenarios under load. Further, SQL Server Engine differences might be involved.  All of this is just par for the course for trying to figure out and debug concurrency issues, especially with an engine involved that has its own very strong notions of concurrency.
2. Rather than going against the grain of the situation by trying to make something work or fully explain a situation, when things are empirically not working, why not change approach by designing for cleaner handling of the problem?

   - One option: acknowledge the reality of SQL Server's need to have a exclusive lock on model db by regulating access via some kind of concurrency synchronization mechanism--a `System.Threading.Monitor` sounds about right for what is happening here and it would allow you to control what happens when there is a timeout, [with a timeout of your choosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h9d380(v=vs.110).aspx).  This will help prevent the kind of locked up type scenario that may be happening on the SQL Server end, which would be an explanation for the current "timeouts" symptom (although stress load might be the sole explanation).
   - Another option: See if you can design in such a way that you don't need to synchronize at all.  Get to a point where you never request more than one database create simultaneously.  Some kind of queue of the create requests--and the queue is guaranteed to be serviced by, say, only one thread--with requesting tasks doing async/await patterns on the result of the creates.

Either way, you are going to have situations where this slows down to a crawl under stress testing, with super stressed loads causing failure. The key questions are:

- Can your design handle some multiple of the likely worst case load and still show acceptable performance?
- If failure does occur, is your response to the failure "controlled" in a way that you have designed for.

Comment: Thanks DWright. I also thought of using a queuing action and have one thread to the create the DB but the solution I went with was I created a "template" database.  Basically, an empty DB that EF creates at app startup then have each task (or tenant) restore the template DB and rename and relocate the corresponding logical db files as their own. It has worked fine for me since then.

Comment: Sounds like a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have different *LockTimeoutSeconds* and *QueryTimeoutSeconds* set on the development and local instances for SSDT (DacFx Deploy), which is deploying the databases.

For example *LockTimeoutSeconds* is used to set [lock_timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lock-timeout-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If you have a small number here, this is the reason for

> Could not obtain exclusive lock on database 'model'. Retry the operation later. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

You can use the query below to identify what timeout is set by SSDT

```
select session_id, lock_timeout, * from sys.dm_exec_sessions where login_name = 'username'
```

To increase the default timeout, find the identifier of the user, which is deploying the database here

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

Then find the following registry key

> HKEY_USERS\your user identifier\Microsoft\VisualStudio\your version\SQLDB\Database

and change the values for *LockTimeoutSeconds* and *QueryTimeoutSeconds*